# Akka Clustering and Large Payloads

Tags: akka, cluster-computing, netty, large-files

I'm writing a specialized distributed storage system using akka clustering and would like to send large payloads (>1MB byte arrays) between actors. I found that I had to edit `akka.remote.netty.tcp.maximum-frame-size` to enable this.

My question is: are there any other performance implications that I need to take into account for this? For example, do I need to further tune netty buffer sizes? Is there a way to minimize the number of copies created?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to think of is that large packages can cause something like head of line blocking where the system messages such as heartbeats will be blocked by sending the large package. In general it is a good idea to split large internode messages up into smaller messages to avoid this.

We are currently working on a new remoting subsystem for Akka which contains a separate large messages channel between nodes and where we also have a separation of regular messages and system messages to avoid those interfering with each other.